# Django Rest Framework - Nested Routers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to make a nested serializer with this URL structure: localhost/ficha/{pk}/propuestas/

I found the drf-nested-routers package and I'm trying to implement it following the examples but I'm not sure if I'm using it in the right way.

url.py

```
router.register(r'fichas', views.FichasViewSet,)
fichas_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'fichas', lookup='propuesta')
fichas_router.register(r'propuestas', views.PropuestaViewSet)

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
    url(r'^', include(fichas_router.urls)),
    [...]
```

views.py

```
class FichasViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Fichas.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FichasSerializer

    def pre_save(self, obj):
        obj.owner = self.request.user

    def post_save(self, obj, created=False):
        obj.group = self.request.user.groups.values_list('id', flat=True)

class PropuestaViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Propuesta.objects.all()

    def list(self, request, domain_pk=None):
        serializer = PropuestaSerializer(queryset, many=True)
        propuestas = self.queryset.filter(domain=domain_pk)
        return Response(serializer.data)

    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None, domain_pk=None):
        propuestas = self.queryset.get(pk=pk, domain=domain_pk)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

I have a TypeError: **new**() takes exactly 5 arguments (4 given)

Comment: Could you solve your problem? Please post the solution then.